# EclipseLink MOXy JSON Bindings, BackSlash '\' escape issue

Tags: java, json, eclipselink, unmarshalling, moxy

I am trying to convert a JSON string to Java Object using EclipseLink MOXy (JSON Bindings). I am getting the below exception when the JSON string contains the '\' character. Below is a sample program of what I am trying to do. What should I do to escape the backslash so that the name attribute in TestBean is populated as "A\B"?

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties;

public class JSONMoxyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestBean.class).createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        String jsonStr = "{\"name\":\"A\\B\"}"; //{"name":"A\B"}
        TestBean bean = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(jsonStr )), TestBean.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(bean.getName());
    }
}

class TestBean {
  private String name;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

Exception:
line 1:10 no viable alternative at character '\'
line 1:11 no viable alternative at character 'B'
line 1:14 mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '"'
line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(-1@[])]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:303)
    at org.gs1us.glnreg.util.usps.JSONMoxyTest.main(JSONMoxyTest.java:17)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(-1@[])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.unmarshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.convertSAXException(SAXUnmarshaller.java:996)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:301)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: NoViableAltException(-1@[])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONParser.value(JSONParser.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONParser.pair(JSONParser.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONParser.object(JSONParser.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONParser.message(JSONParser.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:972)
    ... 6 more
```

I am using these jars: org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.0.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.0.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.5.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON the `\` character must be escaped as `\\`.

**Corrected `JSONMoxyTest`**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties;

public class JSONMoxyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestBean.class).createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        String jsonStr = "{\"name\":\"A\\\\B\"}"; //{"name":"A\\B"}
        TestBean bean = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(jsonStr )), TestBean.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(bean.getName());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
A\B
```